# How to submit post data via urllib2 in python 2.4?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.4

I am trying to submit a POST request with data in json format to create a user using the [Crowd API](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/latest/REST/#usermanagement/1/user-addUser).

Here is the code snippet:

```
url = 'http://crowdserver/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/user'
payload = '{"name": "sampleuser", "password": {"value": "secret"}, "active": true, "first-name": "Sample", "last-name": "User","display-name": "Sample User", "email": "sample@user.cool"}'
req = urllib2.Request(url, payload)
req.add_header('Content-type','application/json')
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
output = resp.read()
print output
print resp.code
```

I get the following output:

```
Bad Request
Error code returned is 400
```

I thought this might perhaps be an encoding issue so replaced payload with:

```
payload = json.dumps({"name": "sampleuser", "password": {"value": "secret"}, "active": true, "first-name": "Sample", "last-name": "User","display-name": "Sample User", "email": "sample@user.cool"})
```

Which returns:

```
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

So it looks like `"active": true` is not in an acceptable format.

If I add double quotes such as `"active":"true"` I get a **TypeError**; `TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object`

**Update**

So the type error was indeed solved by setting the `active` attribute value to `True` but it turns out the `400` error was returned due to `invalid user data, for example missing password or the user already exists` read as `the user already exists` - I find it odd that the error for invalid input and an existing user share the same error code.

Comment: What if you change it to `True`?

Comment: Genuinely curious - what's the use case for such an old Python version?

Comment: Your example code sends a password in plain text over http

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Aware of it. This is just a POC.

Comment: @JoshuaRLi: Running on RH5.11 with no admin access.

Comment: @kaizenCoder ;___; feelsbadman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

`payload = '{"name": "sampleuser", "password": {"value": "secret"}, "active": true, "first-name": "Sample", "last-name": "User","display-name": "Sample User", "email": "sample@user.cool"}'`

Change `..., "active": true, ...` to `..., "active": True, ...`

Python's `True`/`False` are case-sensitive.

Comment: Good point but I'm getting the same error. I'm going to try this via CURL to see if I can figure it out.